# Hapijs + Angularjs cookie session with correct cors configuration not working

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cors, hapi.js

Here is my Cors config in my hapijs app:

```
    "connections": [
        {
            "port": 8067,
            "routes": {
                "cors": {
                    "credentials": true,
                    "origin": ["*"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

I am using the `hapi-auth-cookie` to authenticate the user from a POST from an angular.js front-end. Once the login happens, I am sending a request out to get a list of projects, but the GET request for projects returns a 401.

Here is my angular setup:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8067/projects', {withCredentials: true})
                        .success(function(data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        }).error(function(data,status,error,config){
                            deferred.reject(data);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears there's some issue with the angular `$http` module (see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L929-L931) If you pass in a `withCredentials` into the `$http.get('url_here', config)` (config part of the call), it never gets set.

Instead, to fix this, simply use this code: `$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

Comment: Good investigation @dennismonsewicz I was wondering if you had any opinion on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748102/are-xhr-cookies-more-secure-than-normal-cookies thank you in advance if you do.

Answer (score 0):

It does look to me that withCredentials is getting properly set in the config and I suspect the issue might have to do with something else.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KACel8uVOuYnNTH9izuu?p=preview

Wrt code that you have shared, config is extending the requestConfig object (line:904). So as long as it is set in request config it should be fine.

```
  var config = extend({
    method: 'get',
    transformRequest: defaults.transformRequest,
    transformResponse: defaults.transformResponse,
    paramSerializer: defaults.paramSerializer
  }, requestConfig);
```

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason passing it in with the request didn't work.

Comment: Yeah not sure about the issue but I don't think below fix might be the proper one. Its a toughie but if u can reproduce in a plunkr it would be helpful.